# Form an unordered list with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string (notice how there are new spaces before each hyphen):

```
string = '  - Bullet 1\
  - Bullet 2\
  - Bullet 3\
  - Bullet 4'
```

I would like to replace it using python and regex so that it is a HTML list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Bullet 1</li>
    <li>Bullet 2</li>
    <li>Bullet 3</li>
    <li>Bullet 4</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I would like to replace each bullet with a `<li></li>` tags and then wrap them with `<ul></ul>` tags.

The string will not always remain the same, so I would prefer if there was a way to identify the first bullet list item to place the first `<ul>` and then a way to identify the last bullet list item and then include the `</ul>`.

**Things I've Tried which did not work:**

- `re.sub(r'(\ \ -\ (.*?))', r'<li>\1</li>', string)`
- I read that adding a number to re.sub like `re.sub(r'', r'', string, 1)` would apply something to that occurrence (in this case the first one as it is 1).

**Edit:**

I would prefer if the syntax worked with any string such as:

```
string = 'This is some text  - Bullet 1\
  - Bullet 2\
  - Bullet 3\
  - Bullet 4'
```

As you can see, there is some text at the top which is not in the bullet form. This text may vary or may be after the bullet list etc, so the syntax would have to work with this.

Comment: Is there anything after the string list? So, is it "blah {list} blah" or just "blah {list}"

Comment: Yes that's right there could be something before and/or after the list.

Comment: @PavSidhu In your string the Bullet are in each new line or `\` is only for continuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the bullet items are one on each line like this:

```
>>> string = '''This is some normal text
  - Bullet 1
  - Bullet 2
  - Bullet 3
  - Bullet 4
This is other text at the end'''
```

also another bullet list without surrounding text:

```
>>> string2 = '''  - Bullet 1
  - Bullet 2
  - Bullet 3
  - Bullet 4'''
```

With two simple substitutions you can replace the bullets also in the middle of normal text:

```
def htmlize(txt):
    return re.sub('  - ([^\n]*)', r'<li>\1</li>',
        re.sub('((  - [^\n]*(\n|$))+)', r'<ul>\n\1\n</ul>', txt))
```

Tests:

```
>>> htmlize(string)
'This is some normal text\n<ul>\n<li>Bullet 1</li>\n<li>Bullet 2</li>\n<li>Bullet 3</li>\n
<li>Bullet 4</li>\n\n</ul>This is other text at the end'
>>> htmlize(string2)
'<ul>\n<li>Bullet 1</li>\n<li>Bullet 2</li>\n<li>Bullet 3</li>\n<li>Bullet 4</li>\n</ul>'
```

Edit:

```
>>> string3 = 'This is some text to introduce the bullet points:\n  - This is the first bullet points\n  - This is the second bullet point\n  - This is the third bullet point\nThis some last bit of text.'
>>> htmlize(string3)
'This is some text to introduce the bullet points:\n<ul>\n<li>This is the first bullet points</li>\n<li>This is the second bullet point</li>\n<li>This is the third bullet point</li>\n\n</ul>This some last bit of text.'
```

Comment: Ah that was a mistake, just fixed it. I think we should delete these comments now to remove unneeded comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '''  - Bullet 1
  - Bullet 2
  - Bullet 3
  - Bullet 4'''

newstring = [line[4:].join(['<li>', '</li>']) if
             line.startswith('  - ') else line for line in string.split('\n')]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(*newstring, sep='\n')
<li>Bullet 1</li>
<li>Bullet 2</li>
<li>Bullet 3</li>
<li>Bullet 4</li>
```

Comment: I presume it's [the meta-effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow/297878#comment212534_297900) you mentioned. 1+ to counter the ignorance. (Excellent, well thought-out [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297900/2680216), by the way.)

Comment: You're missing the `<ul>` around the list with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting first every item you want from each `Bullet`(for example) then joining the returned list to your needed form, this way:

```
s = 'This is some text  - Bullet 1\
  - Bullet 2\
  - Bullet 3\
  - Bullet 4 And some text here'

r = re.findall(r'\w+\s+\d+', s) #Get all items from your `string`
in_Block = ['   '+t.join(['<li>','</li>']) for t in r] #join your items to construct inside block
out_Block = '\n'.join(in_Block).join(['<li>\n','\n</li>']) #Form the Outer Block
>>> print out_Block
<li>
   <li>Bullet 1</li>
   <li>Bullet 2</li>
   <li>Bullet 2</li>
   <li>Bullet 4</li>
</li>
>>>
```